# Shift right and left with 3D data by matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have one code to shift left and shift right with 2D data in Matlab. There are codes

```
function shift = shiftL(M)
  shift = [ M(:,2:size(M,2)) M(:,size(M,2)) ];

function shift = shiftR(M)
  shift = [ M(:,1) M(:,1:size(M,2)-1) ];
```

I want to apply above codes to 3D data input. How to modify above codes for 3D data? Thank you

```
function shift = shiftL3D(M)


function shift = shiftR3D(M)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function shift = shiftL3D(M)
    shift = cat (3, M(:,:,2:size(M,3)) , M(:,:,1) );
function shift = shiftR3D(M)
    shift = cat (3,M(:,:,end), M(:,:,1:size(M,3)-1) )
```

Comment: Thank you michaeltang. If I want to transpose matrix after right shift. Is it possible? This is 2D transport shift = shiftR(M')';. When I apply it for 3D it has error that is Error using  '.Transpose on ND array is not defined.

Comment: as the error message tells, transpose on ND array is not defined, It is impossible.

Comment: since 3d matrix has 3 dim so it can transpose to 6 different order, permute can do that

Answer (score 0):

```
function shift = shiftL3D(M)
  shift = cat(size(M,3),M(:,:,2:size(M,3)), M(:,:,1));

function shift = shiftR3D(M)
  shift = cat(size(M,3),M(:,:,end),M(:,:1:size(M,3)-1));
```

Comment: I try to apply your code but this is error Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in shiftR (line 120)
  shift = [ M(:,:,end) M(:,:,1:size(M,3)-1) ];

Comment: @user3051460 my bad.please see my revision:)